# Better way of using different colors for different pages

Tags: css, themes

I'm currently using different colors for different pages and then call them in the body-tag like this

CSS:

```
#theme-green .whateverdiv {color: green;}
```

HTML:

```
<body id="theme-green">
```

Problem is when I have a lot of elements that needs to be styled, do I have to add `#theme-green` on every element or could I "wrap" all elements under the `#theme-green` tag?

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
#theme-green
{
   .thingnumber1 {stuff here;}
   .thingnumber2 {stuff here;}
   .thingnumber3 {stuff here;}
}
```

Instead of this:

```
#theme-green .thingnumber1 {stuff here;}
#theme-green .thingnumber2 {stuff here;}
#theme-green .thingnumber3 {stuff here;}
```

Kind regards,

Emil

Comment: Have a look at SASS if you want to nest items http://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't, with pure CSS at least.

Assuming that your elements share common styles, your CSS would need to be structured like this...

```
#theme-green .thingnumber1,
#theme-green .thingnumber2,
#theme-green .thingnumber3 {
    stuff here;
}
```

If you wish to do as you suggest in your question you could use a CSS Preprocessor such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).